# Documentation for "appropriate, standard legal practice" in rendering written decisions

Tags: reference-request

A question arose while reading ["Impartial hearings under the IDEA: legal issues and answers."](http://www.nasdse.org/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=nTeBfmZi_Aw%3D&tabid=36) IHO = Impartial Hearing Officer in a special education impartial hearing (a type of administrative hearing).

> Does the IDEA provide any standards for IHO competence?
>
> The IDEA competency standards require IHOs to: [...]
>
> (iv) possess the knowledge and ability to **render and write decisions in accordance with appropriate, standard legal practice**.
>
> 20 U.S.C. § 1415(f)(3)(A) (2008).

The IHO who wrote the decision I'm appealing did an incredibly slapdash job, with spelling errors, grammar errors, factual errors and incorrect references.  I would like a reference I can cite that shows that submitting a decision by "appropriate, standard legal practice" means, among other things, proofreading your document, or at least running your decision through a spell checker!  (I don't mean the documentation would say that specifically, of course.)

Comment: Note that "possessing ... the ability" is not negated by neglecting to employ the ability in a particular case.

Comment: In the US, administrative actions are assumed to be legally correct unless there is a substantial violation of procedural requirements (failure to follow the stated rules), an egregious bias (the outcome was demonstrably pre-determined), or actual violation of the law.

Comment: I'm with feetwet's reasoning on this and would also note that you have to show not just error, but that the error was not harmless. A sloppy opinion doesn't obviously hurt you in an way.

Answer (score 2):

You are wasting your time trying to argue that spelling errors, grammar errors or incorrect references are examples of "**in**appropriate, standard legal practice" because they aren't. They are certainly examples of poor English and writing skills and possibly of a less than professional approach, however, that is **not** what is required.

You are on slightly better ground with an argument about incorrect facts except that it is quite likely that such errors will not be overturned by a court because providing the IMO has complied with the general requirements of [Adjudication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_administrative_law#Adjudication) under administrative legal principles or the specific requirements of the statute *they are entitled to be wrong*. That is the adjudicator is expected to carry out their *decision making* role in accordance with the law and providing they have done so, it doesn't matter how many other people (including judges) think they made the wrong decision - it was their decision to make.

Further, even if you could demonstrate that the particular IHO was not competent to be an IMO, it does not follow that a decision made while they were an IMO is therefore void.

To have the decision reviewed you would need to demonstrate that it violated a general provision of administrative law, such as by failing to hold a hearing in accordance with the relevant law or failing to afford one of the parties [natural justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_justice) or that the IMO had acted outside jurisdiction.